# How to set a condition in a setHTML block ? (Mapbox popup)

Tags: twig, mapbox, craftcms

I'm using mapbox-gl-js on a craftcms website.
This is a script block inside a Twig template.

I'm rendering markers with data via a geoJSON with some properties ->

```
"properties": {
    ...
    "phoneNumber": locationPhone[k],
    "faxNumber": locationFax[k],
    ...
}
```

On click, markers displays an Info-box with some data from the `geoJSON` via `setHTML`

```
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
                            .setHTML(`
                            ...
                <li class="phoneNumber">
                   <span class="green">Tel.</span> <span class="display-phone">${myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber}</span>
                </li>
```

So at this point, we have (php?) variables in a setHTML in a script tag in a Twig template.

How could I set a condition around

```
<li class="phoneNumber">
</li>
```

so this 'li' would only be displayed if `locationPhone[k]` or `${myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber}` is set ?

I've gone so far with limited knowledge, I fear I've done it wrong and can't check for this property now.

Edit : If anybody needs this, those variables provided by ARCGIS are geoJson objects, they can be accessed like this :

```
if (myCustomLayers.properties.faxNumber === undefined) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("faxNumber")[0].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber === undefined) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("phoneNumber")[0].style.display = "none";
                    
                }
                console.log(myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber)
```

Finally sorted it out. Thanks

Comment: `${myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber}` is not a valid twig syntax?

Comment: Yes you are correct, but I've found this on https://developers.arcgis.com/mapbox-gl-js/layers/display-a-popup/ and it's working perfectly to display my geoJSON data, I've just no idea how to wrap it into a condition so that it would not be displayed if it's undefined

Comment: Could you try to log this, `console.log('${myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber}');`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't realise ${myCustomLayers.properties.phoneNumber} were Json objects, so I just read the documentation for accessing these and eventually made it work (edited main post). Thanks!